# Как сделать в Unity realtime Editor?

Tags: unity3d, realtime

Очень часто встает задача поработать с объектами сцены во время игры как в редакторе. Например расставить объекты в редакторе уровня, покрутить головоломку в 3D и т.д. т.п..  Все это очень удобно делать в редакторе: выделять один или несколько объектов сцены, вращать, двигать в пространстве, приближать камеру к объекту, вращать и двигать камеру.

Есть в AssetStore плагины заточенные под это, может кому попадались? А то я сам затрудняюсь определиться по каким тэгам искать)

Comment: Возможно, натыкался на похожие вопросы на иностранном гугле. Но что именно вы имеете ввиду? Во время игры в самом редакторе и так можно делать что-нибудь с объектами

Comment: @KremSoda интересует именно в самой игре как в редакторе управлять объектом (двигать, вращать, масштабировать), а также управлять наблюдателем (двигать, вращать, изменять FOV)

Comment: я могу все это сделать и сам, времени жалко, если что-то подобное уже есть в AssetStore, то проще было бы купить

Answer (score 1):

[**Runtime Transform Gizmos**](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/runtime-transform-gizmos-125537)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Личное ИМХО: оно того не стоит, если все, что нужно - менять position/rotation/scale, то действительно проще написать подобное самостоятельно.

---

Что касается "приближать камеру к объекту, вращать и двигать камеру" - это сделать самостоятельно еще проще, но и для таких задач есть ассет:

**[Freelook Camera](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/camera/freelook-camera-21411)**